# Can I run lamp and linux terminal commands simultaneously on Ubuntu server?

Tags: linux, terminal, ubuntu-server

I am making a project where I have to run sudo commands on Ubuntu server while **lamp** server is deploying a website.

Is it possible to run two terminals on one Ubuntu server?
Or, put another way, how can I run sudo commands while running an apache server?

Comment: Hi Aryan. Welcome! What research have you done and what have you tried? Share some command line pieces of script that you have tried and what the result was.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are looking for a tool like tmux - it allows you to have multiple terminals in a single ssh connection. Even more - it preserves terminals for you when disconnected. You can also use it also as a collaboration tool.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmux - give it a shot, it looks not very intuitive at start, but after you master it becomes important tool in your toolbelt.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can run commands in multiple terminals.
However, while running/deploying a website, I prefer my projects to be handled by certain managers to run when the terminal closes. I use `pm2` for nodejs and similarly other tools are available for your projects of preferred language.